# Trying to give UILabel a shadow, but it won't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiview, uilabel

I'm trying to give a label in one of the classes in my app a drop shadow, but it's not working at all. Nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Set label properties
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:TITLE_FONT_SIZE];
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
titleLabel.opaque = YES;
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textColor = titleLabelColor;
titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
```

It's just white, no shadow.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but `opaque` should be `NO`. Also, that's a pretty big `shadowOffset`.

Comment: what about the `clipsToBounds` property?

Comment: are you sure your titleLabelColor is not backColor? also, I think offset of 10,10 is way too large, and your shadow may be going out of viewbounds. Try setting it as (any) combo of 1 and -1

Comment: shadow will apply to text of `UILabel` and its possible when you apply it on `Layer`, add `QuartzCore` framework in you project and apply shadow on `Layer` of `UILabel`.

Comment: Show all the code for creating the label and setting the label text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just Add this line to before adding titleLabel to self.view

```
 titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm creating a button programmatically, and before I add it to the view, I'm calling button.titleLabel?.layer.masksToBounds = false, but still my shadows get cropped at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

i hope you are aware of categories?

Creating a category will be better option:

`Command + N > Objective-C Category > Category = Animation & Category on = UIView`
This will create 2 files with name `UIView+Animation.h` and `UIView+Animation.m`

`UIView+Animation.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface UIView (Animation)
- (void)setBackgroundShadow:(UIColor *)shadowColor CGSize:(CGSize)CGSize shadowOpacity:(float)shadowOpacity shadowRadius:(float)shadowRadius;
@end
```

`UIView+Animation.m` file

```
#import "UIView+Animation.h"

@implementation UIView (Animation)
- (void)setBackgroundShadow:(UIColor *)shadowColor CGSize:(CGSize)CGSize shadowOpacity:(float)shadowOpacity shadowRadius:(float)shadowRadius
{
    self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
    self.clipsToBounds = NO;
}
```

Import `UIView+Animation.h` in any of your `viewController` and call it like this:

```
[self.titleLabel  setBackgroundShadow:[UIColor grayColor] CGSize:CGSizeMake(0, 5) shadowOpacity:1 shadowRadius:5.0];
```

Comment: I changed the name of the second method parameter to shadowOffset.  A minor tweak, but I find the code more readable that way.  Plus it avoids using a parameter name that conflicts with an iOS type.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you allocate the UILabel and also set a frame for the label. And also make sure that view is added to the subview. Something like this:

```
    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30)];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    titleLabel.opaque = YES;
    titleLabel.text = @"My Label";
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
    [myView addSubview:titleLabel];
    [titleLabel release];
```

value 10 for shadow offset is quite big. You can tweak the values based on your requirements.

Comment: Make sure that height of the label and the shadow offset you are specifying arent the same. If so then, you will never see the shadow because, it will go out off bounds.